# How to register my unregistered account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, sign-up

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist)

I've been using my SO account for couple of days, but I am not registered and I do not want to lose all my questions. How can I register and keep my questions from my unregistered account?