# Registration with my unregistered account

Tags: support, stack-overflow, merge-accounts

I am using this nickname which has some reputation and email.

How can I properly register with this name and not lose my reputation, question and posts while having more privileges and the ability to mark answers?

Comment: Because you have a username I think you've done all you need to do ... I'm confused.

Comment: @drackenstern, @EveryoneElseWho'sReadingThis: I think he's looking for the SO FAQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to register my unregistered account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42267/how-to-register-my-unregistered-account)

Comment: @drachenstern The user's SO account is an unregistered account, not a registered account. That's what he's referring to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You appear to be unregistered on Meta. If you have registered at stackoverflow, all you have to do is:
Go over to meta.stackoverflow.com(if you are reading this you are already there) and click [Log in](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login) 
Select your open id provider and login using the same credentials you used while registering for the SO account, Meta (and any other SE site) will detect and merge your accounts.

Meanwhile if you are [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/users/559792/byakugan) then you are unregistered on stackoverflow too. you need to go over to stackoverflow.com's [login](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login) from the same browser that you have been using your unregistered account from, hope that stackoverflow recognizes you(because if you have cleared cookies or changed browser, stackoverflow will not recognize you), if SO recognizes you, you can select an openid service provider and login to register your account.

Finally if SO does not recognize you(you have cleared your browser cookies) then go over to
[Account recovery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery) and enter your email address that you used while posting questions or answers. SO will mail you a link which you can then use to register your account. 
[image: register]

(edited screenshot)

To register click on your user name in the top bar and then click on the Register link in your profile. Then select a open id provider of your choice. 
(You can also click on the register link next to your username)

After registering, you will be able to login using the same open id provider to access your account. You can add multiple openid providers later on.

So basically if you remember the email id you used while asking your question you can recover your account and If you are already registered you can merge accounts.

Comment: Somehow I did it through google email address ... But I dont have reputation from stack owerflow here s it normal?

Comment: @Byakugan I don't know how it works now, but when I joined 5 months back, my meta.SO reputation was independent of my stackoverflow reputation. For SO's sister sites like serverfault, the meta and parent reputations are the same.

Comment: I merged and registered and cannot set this answer ...

Comment: You did something wrong there chap. However, this is the place to be, we'll get someone to clean that up for you shortly. Hang tight.

Comment: @Byakugan try [the recovery on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery)